# text editor - duplicate strings by pattern

Tags: string, text, replace, duplicates, editor

I have a number of html input tags with id

```
<input id="someID" />
```

I have the need to add the field name to every input tag.
Do you know a text editor that is able to duplicate every string id="something", and then replace "id" with "name" ?

```
<input id="yyy" name ="yyy" />
```

I always use notepadpp for this kind of operations, but i think it can't handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use active regular expressions and process a global search and replace action to do the job.

Regex on - Search for:

```
(<input id=")(.*?)(" />)
```

Replace with:

```
<input id="$2" name="$2" />
```

Second pair of round brackets will isolate name of id and make it accessible as variable in replacement. If your editor is not capable of regex you should install **Sublime Text**. It´s free and just an awesome code-editor.